# Editing files in place with perl from powershell

Tags: perl, powershell

I have a list of files files.txt in a directory.  I want to run a text substitution through each file.

```
$f = (get-content files.txt)
Foreach ($i in $f) { perl -pi -we "s/(\d{0,4})- /$1 - /g" $i }
```

But perl doesn't like to do this without making a backup.

> Can't do inplace edit without backup.

So I added the .bak to -i:

```
$f = (get-content files.txt)
Foreach ($i in $f) { perl -pi.bak -we "s/(\d{0,4})- /$1 - /g" $i }
```

And now it complains:

> Can't open perl script ".bak": No such file or directory

What am I missing?

UPDATE:

What I would prefer is a way to do this without a shell entirely.  Can I do this loop in perl with just `$^I` somehow?

Comment: On Windows, it is necessary to put the -i.bak switch on its own. Like, perl -i.bak -pwe...   Are you sure you want \d{0.4} and not \d{1,4}

Comment: @Chris Charley, That's not true. Perl on Windows accepts `-pi.bak` perfectly fine. That said, PowerShell appears to pass something other than `-pi.bak` (specifically, `-pi .bak`), so that might be the right things to do for *PowerShell*.

Comment: @wdkrnls, `perl -pi.bak -we "s/(\d{0,4})- /$1 - /g"` is fine for `cmd`. This appears to be a problem specific to PowerShell.

Comment: Thanks, Chris!  You were right that I wanted \d{1,4}.  But placing -i.bak didn't change the error.  I'm using DWIM perl 5.14.2.

Comment: Perl is receiving some whitespace between `-i` and `.bak`. Don't know why. (Don't have and never used PowerShell.)

Comment: I'm curious why you aren't doing this all in PS?

Comment: The problem here is that PowerShell parser will try to parse you perl code, and obviously will make it useless once it will pass it to perl executable... There are few ways around it, including creating wrapper for perl, or using start-process magic to force PS to ignore tokens that are have different meaning in Powershell (like -foo). But tbh I don't see why, if you are already using PowerShell, not use: { $i -replace '(\d{1,4})', '$1' } or something along those lines instead of perl...? :)

Comment: @EBGreen,@BartekB:  Alright, I'll try it.

Comment: I tried: Foreach ($i in $f) { $i -replace "(\d{1,4})- ", "$1 - " } but it didn't actually change the files.  Doesn't -replace only do string substitution and not in-place editing like the perl script would have?

Comment: You would have to pipe the resulting string back to the file so something like  ($i in $f) { $i -replace "(\d{1,4})- ", "$1 - " | Out-File $i -Force}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my $qfn = 'files.txt';
open(my $fh, '<', $qfn)
   or die("Can't open file list \"$qfn\": $!\n");

local @ARGV = <$fh>;
local $^I = '.bak';
local $_;
while (<>) {
   s/(\d{0,4})- /$1 - /g;
   print;
}
```

---

`\d` matches more than 0-9 when /a isn't used, so you probably want

```
 s/(\d{0,4})- /$1 - /ag;
   -or-
 s/([0-9]{0,4})- /$1 - /g;
```

Note that the above doesn't prevent 5 digits from being matched as you appear to want. To do that, use:

```
 s/(?<![0-9])([0-9]{0,4})- /$1 - /g;
```

Now, there's no reason to replace the number with itself when you know about `\K`.

```
 s/(?<![0-9])[0-9]{0,4}\K- / - /g;
```

And finally, we can get rid of the duplicate `-` too.

```
 s/(?<![0-9])[0-9]{0,4}\K(?=- )/ /g;
```

Answer (score 1):

ikegami was absolutely correct. In powershell -i.bak is interpreted as -i .bak. The solution is to force powershell to pass it as single argument.

Like
    perl '-pi.bak' -we .... # enclose them in single quotes.